# use session and still be ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsp, colorbox

i am using ajax and jsp, but instead of using out.write() in jsp side, i do write the response string into session o object, then i open a colorbox panel and write the session value into page.

is doing this make my site not-ajax?

i understand that using querystring is an other way around, what is the difference between my solution and  querystring  solution?

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. AJAX is just a process for letting the client talk to the server without reloading the page. A lot of people think it is all of the dynamic behavior on the page as well, but that's been there before AJAX was first made possible in 2005 when Microsoft added the XMLHttpRequest object to IE.